# Is Flink KeyedStream sum() function stateful?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-state, flink-stateful-functions

Let's write a simple wordcount job

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
        text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
                .keyBy(value -> value.f0)
                .sum(1);
```

(source and other details are irrilevant)
Suppose into the pipeline arrives the string

```
"the cat is on the table"
```

Result is:

```
<the - 1>
<cat - 1>
<is - 1>
<on - 1>
<the - 2>
<table - 1>
```

The only word found twice is "the".
It seems that `sum()` function is stateful, mainteing at least the last <word - count> tuple updates when a new tuple <word, 1> arrives (obviosly partitioned by word value).
If it is true, and checkpointing is enabled, is this "state" saved into checkpoint and recovered in case of failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Source code

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/aggregation/SumAggregator.java

uses an AggregateFunction

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html

which is stateful